# For-Next Loop in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want to compute for the binomial coefficient in Visual basic but I can only do the numerator part as I am lost on the denominator part. The equation that I am using is seen in the image below.

[Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtJTu.jpg)

Looking at the C(n,k) equation, I can only do the numerator which is the n factorial. I am having trouble with the denominator. My code for the numerator (n!) is below:

```
Dim nfactorial As Integer = 1
    For i As Integer = 1 To txt3.Text
       nfactorial *= i
    Next
```

What should I do about the denominator part? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't separately calculate numerator and denominator. Have you try finding (30!) in .NET, especially with `Integer` ?
Is this a homework? Anyway, just take a look at following post: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/calculate-the-binomial-coefficient-n-choose-k-efficiently-in-c/

Code in vb:

```
Dim result As Decimal = 1
For i As Integer = 1 To K
    result *= N - (K - i)
    result /= i
Next
Return result
```

Comment: I forgot to add that in my question only the N value is user-input. From your given example, both the N and K are user-input.

Comment: Thanks for the help tho! :)

Comment: What is the different, you can set `Dim K as Decimal = txt3.Text`

Comment: Maybe you can answer this question? :) 

Let's say n is still the only user-input. If n = 3. What I want is to get the C(n,k) for C(3,0), C(3,1), C(3,2), and C(3,3). Will the code above still work for this example?

Comment: @Sonson Glad you solved it. Wrap out side with another loop for N value?

Comment: I used nested For-Next loop. I used the equation above. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'by example: C(5,3) = 10
Dim n, k As Integer
Dim result As String = ""
n = txt3.Text
For k = 0 To 3
    result = result & "For C(" & n & "," & k & ")=" & C(n, k) & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox(result)
.  
.
.

Private Function C(n As Integer, k As Integer)
    Dim result As Decimal = 1
    For i As Integer = 1 To k
        result *= n - (k - i)
        result /= i
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

**EDIT**: For `k=0 to 3` and `n` entered by keyboard.

Comment: This code works. However, in this example both the n and k are user-input. While in my case, only the n is user-input (i forgot to mention, apologies). Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Check the code, `n` gets the value of your `textbox` and `k` is a constant value that can change according to your requirement.

Comment: Another question. N is still the only user-input. If n = 3. And I want to get the C(n,k) for C(3,0), C(3,1), C(3,2), and C(3,3). Will the code above still work for this example?

Comment: I know I just have to change the k value to 0,1,2 or 3. But what if the desired result is to get all values at the same time?